# Difference result for RegExp in the V8Js on PHP and Console Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, regex, v8js

I have this JS code:

```
var str = "foo bar";
var res1 = str.replace(new RegExp('foo\\b', 'g'), "BAZ");
var res2 = str.replace(new RegExp('foo', 'g'), "BAZ");
console.log("Result1: " + res1 + " Result2: " + res2);
```

The result on Console of `Chrome Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)` is:

`Result1: BAZ bar Result2: BAZ bar`

Now I test same code on `PHP` with `V8Js` extension:

PHP code:

```
<?php
$v8 = new V8Js();
$JS = <<<EOT
var str = "foo bar";
var res1 = str.replace(new RegExp('foo\\b', 'g'), "BAZ");
var res2 = str.replace(new RegExp('foo', 'g'), "BAZ");
print("Result1: " + res1 + " Result2: " + res2);
EOT;
echo $v8->executeString($JS);
```

Result on the `PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2018 05:57:41) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )` With `V8Js Version 2.1.0` extension:

`Result1: foo bar Result2: BAZ bar`

Why difference result for `result1`?!!!

Comment: Try the PHP test with the input string, "foob bar". It could be that PHP is interpreting the `\\\` in your JavaScript source.

Comment: @Pointy good point, Do you like as a answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) which is equivalent with `"`.
That means it will interpret the `\` as escaping.

If you use [Nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) it will be equivalent with  `'` thus not escape the backslash.

It's not completley obvious when you read the manual but you need to read about Nowdoc to see that Heredoc is double quote.

> Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings.

That means change your string declaration to:

```
$JS = <<<'EOD'
var str = "foo bar";
var res1 = str.replace(new RegExp('foo\\b', 'g'), "BAZ");
var res2 = str.replace(new RegExp('foo', 'g'), "BAZ");
print("Result1: " + res1 + " Result2: " + res2);
EOD;
```